# How to get small tick mark instead of green text in span- Jquery

Tags: jquery

For the password validation I used jquery and if the password not matched it will print "invalid password" in green color on the document. Instead of that, I want a small green tick mark. How can I do that?
jquery

```
$('#confirm_pass_msg').html('Password Matched').css('color', 'green');
```

html

```
<span id="confirm_pass_msg"></span>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some icon library like [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) and just simply use `addClass()` with the icon you need:

```js
$('#confirm_pass_msg').addClass('fa fa-check').css('color', 'green');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="confirm_pass_msg"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

`$('#confirm_pass_msg').html('✔').css('color', 'green');`

Comment: For best compatibility, you should use `&#x2714` rather than a unicode character

Comment: @freedomn-m I don't know about compatibility of using unicode symbol directly in html code, have no problem in modern browsers, but yes, that's the safer way. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
$('#confirm_pass_msg').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to have tick mark is using icons. Which will work with all browsers and JS versions. I would recommend fonrawesome for the same. You can see the referene [here](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=tryicons_fa-check)

In the code snippet, there is a red tick mark, you can change css to green and you can see a green tick mark:

```
<i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size:48px;color:green"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<span id="confirm_pass_msg">
      <i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size:30px;color:green"></i>
   </span>`